# Query with understanding Borel Set

Tags: probability

I'm just trying to understand what the sentence below means.

A real valued function $X : Ω → R$ defined on $Ω$ is said to be a random variable if for every Borel set $B ⊂ R$, we have

$X^{-1}(B) = \{ω : X(ω) ∈ B\} ∈ F$

where $Ω$ is a set of outcomes called the sample space, $F$ is a set of events.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that putting a definition in the middle of another definition may be confusing.  How about this.

(1) Let $f \colon E \to F$ be a function and $B \subseteq F$.  Then $f^{-1}(B)$ means $\{ e \in E : f(e) \in B\}$.

(2) Let $\Omega$ be a space and $\cal F$ a sigma-algebra of subsets.  A function $X \colon \Omega \to \mathbb R$ is called a **random variable** if for every Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb R$, we have
$$
X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal F
$$

Comment: Wouldn’t you want to include your $\mathscr F$ in the definiend? Something like “r.v. with respect to $\mathscr F$”. The quoted definition is truly dreadful, in my opinion.